# auto add like for users

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i want add user like to post on page load i.e i want to make the like botton show liked if user already liked the post but it not working
this is my ajax code

```
for (var l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
          this_comment_id = $('#like_check_'+l).attr('data-id');
              $.ajax({  
                    url:"comment_post.php",  
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data:{comment_check:this_comment_id},  
                    dataType: 'text',  
                    success:function(data)
                    {  
                          if (data.search("ok") > -1) {
                                $('#like_check_'+l).addClass("red_heart");
                          }else if(data.search("unliked") > -1){
                                $('#like_check_'+l).removeClass("red_heart");
                          }
                    }
              })
    }
```

it is meant to add the red_hearth to liked post by the user in this html element

```
<i onclick="like_post(this)" class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I like it"></i>
<i onclick="like_post(this)" class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="2" id="like_check_1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I like it"></i>
<i onclick="like_post(this)" class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="3" id="like_check_2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I like it"></i>
<i onclick="like_post(this)" class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="4" id="like_check_3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I like it"></i>
<i onclick="like_post(this)" class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="5" id="like_check_4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I like it"></i>
```

but it is not working
**this is my php code for the ajax request**

```
if (isset($_POST['comment_check'])) {
  $get_comment_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, test_input($_POST['comment_check']));
  $get_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $commentcheck = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comment_like` WHERE `liker_id` = '$get_user_id' AND`comment_id` = '$get_comment_id' AND liked='Y'") or exit(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($commentcheck)>0){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "unliked";
}
```

}

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: why issue 5 ajax requests when you could easily use a single query?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius how can i use a single query for the ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I really do not use jQuery it would be folly to try to answer the question using it and thus making mistooks so understand that is why I answer here with vanilla Javascript. Not knowing the table schema, what the function `like_post` does or how somebody can `unlike` something all pose questions but making certain assumptions one can ignore that here.

If you modify the HTML slightly to remove the ID attributes ( which really are not required )

```
<i class='fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3' data-id='1' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='I like it'></i>
<i class='fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3' data-id='2' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='I like it'></i>
<i class='fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3' data-id='3' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='I like it'></i>
<i class='fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3' data-id='4' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='I like it'></i>
<i class='fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3' data-id='5' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='I like it'></i>
```

Then you can collect the `data-id` values from the HTML elements - presumably these will not always be simply `1,2,3,4,5` but will in fact be IDs from articles or whatever from db - so could in-fact be more like `23,6,98,123,5` ( ? )

```
var iCol=document.querySelectorAll( 'i[data-id]' );
var ids=[];

iCol.forEach( i=>{
    ids.push( i.dataset.id )
});
```

With all the relevant IDs you can issue your single Ajax query to the server which will use the IDs in processing which of the `things` the user has previously liked. As the following is basic `jQuery` and only lightly modified from your original I use that here rather than using `XMLHttpRequest` or `Fetch`

```
$.ajax({  
    url:'comment_post.php',  
    type:'POST', 
    data:{ comment_check:ids },  // send the collected IDs
    dataType:'text',  
    success:function(json){
        json.liked.forEach( id => {
            document.querySelector('i[ data-id="'+id+'" ]').classList.add('red_heart')
        })
    }
});
```

The PHP script to check the db:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    
    if( isset( $_POST['comment_check'] ) ) {
        
        $payload=[];
        $ids=explode( ',', $_POST['comment_check'] );
        
        $sql='select `comment_id` from `comment_like` where `liker_id`=? and `liked`="Y"';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $_SESSION['user_id'] );
        $status=$stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result( $cid );
        
        
        $payload['status']=$status;
        $payload['user_id']=$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $payload['liked']=[];
        
        
        while( $stmt->fetch() ){
            if( in_array( $cid, $ids ) ) $payload['liked'][]=$cid;
        }
    
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $payload ) );
    }

?>
```